# export default was not found; module export not working

Tags: javascript, webpack

with encore webpack, I do add a js file:

```js
Encore
.addEntry('js/request', './assets/js/request.js')
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
.splitEntryChunks()
...
```

Inside the request.js, I import a custom module:

```js
import Request from './request';

console.log(Request);
window.Request = Request;
```

Which is exported in request/index.js:

```js
export default () => ({
    url: null,
    options: { method: 'GET' },
    response: null,
    load() {
        ...
```

Pretty straight forward actually.
BUT - when I compile this, I get a warning:

> warning  in ./assets/js/request.js
>
> > "export 'default' (imported as 'Request') was not found in './request'

And *undefined* is logged for that `console.log(Request);` command.

Usually this happens, when you don't export as default but I do and somehow don't? This doesn't make sense at all for me. I'm pretty new to webpack and couln't find a helpful hint so far...

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, I've put a `request.js` and a `request/index.js` into the same folder.
So when I `import ./request` inside `request.js`, its gonna import itself due to the hierarchy of the import file detection.

Now I will just put all the files into a separate folder `/entries` and will be able to `import ../request`. Importing explicitly `import ./request/index.js` will also work.

I guess this just has to happen once, when you start with modules, webpack and stuff...